# Position two userform with no space between them

Tags: vba, excel, userform

How can I adjust the userforms positions inorder to place them side by side when Intialized i.e. remove the space between them.

[image]

From the answer I tried this but it doesn't work

```
CIF.Show
With CIF
    .Top = Application.Top + 5
    .Left = Application.Left + 10
End With

Instructions.Show
With Instructions
    .Top = Application.Top + 5
    .Left = CIF.Left + CIF.Width
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Sub test()
With CIF
.Show vbModeless
.Left = .Left - .Width / 2
End With
With Instructions
.Show vbModeless
.Left = .Left - .Width / 2
End With
Unload CIF
Unload Instructions
End sub
```

[image]

**UPDATED**: 
To avoid overlap
Seems like there's a constant value 7 among the close button and the border of the userform. Following should address it (doesn't matter userform size).

```
Sub test()
With CIF
.Show vbModeless
.Left = .Left - .Width / 2
End With
With Instructions
.Show vbModeless
.Left = CIF.Left + CIF.Width + 7
End With
Unload CIF
Unload Instructions
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it kinda overlaps I guess need to tweak something since CIF width is  499.5 and Instructions width is 423.75

Comment: The Instructions form doesn't move even a little bit form it's position horizontally.

Comment: I think the trick to don't overlap is to find the right position between the close and the border of the user form, I have tried different sizes and seems to be constantly 7, try now the updated one

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work I am out of ideas if you wish to download and experiment with it the file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp8bisqua33usux/Copy_of_HHC_CIF_v010.xlsm?dl=0 thanks I know you provided correct answers but it doesn't works I tried everything.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Left` option of the second form to the `Left` of the first form + `Width` of the first one

```
UserForm2.Left = UserForm1.Left + UserForm1.Width
```

On Windows 7 i had to add another 7 pixels, so like this:

```
UserForm2.Left = UserForm1.Left + UserForm1.Width + 7
```

You might have to modify this depending on the OS

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't works. I have win 10 and it's on a laptop with 1366 x 768 res

Comment: Why isn't it working? Are they not aligned? Explain a bit please

Comment: I it always show like this I can adjust the Top parameter but no matter what i provide to the left parameter they always have that space between them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `StartUpPosition` property to Manual (value = 0, I believe).  Then, you can adjust the top and left placement to remove the gap